# Include more than one file in negative RewriteCond

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using this rule to ignore index.php in rewritte rule:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/?$ galeria.php?nome=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But I need to include bio.php and contact.php in this rule. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need logical OR, e.g. `(condition1|condition2|conditionN)`

```
RewriteRule ^((?!(index\.php|bio\.php|contact\.php)[^/]+)/?$ galeria.php?nome=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```